# Posting links(image url or website url) on Instagram as caption from iOS

Tags: ios, instagram

I am sharing images from my iOS app to `instagram`. I am posting image and captions in the request and that is working fine.

Now what I have to do is that I am sending some `image link` as caption. When I open the instagram, those are posted. But I need to show it as `clickable link`. How this can be done? Does the `instagram` API provides this functionality or I need to do some thing from my app? Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks and regards,
Sreelash

Comment: Hi, did you find answer to this question yet.?

Comment: Hi, I couldn't make it working. What I had found is that it's not possible with Instagram.

Answer (score 0):

According to their [blog post](http://developers.instagram.com/post/125972775561/removing-pre-filled-captions-from-mobile-sharing), no prefilled captions are possible anymore.